# apt-file regex: escaping a dot

Tags: apt, bash, perl, regex, apt-file

I want to find all packages which provide a shared object containing "ssl" in the file name. The [apt-file manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/apt-file.1.html) says:

> --regexp | -x
>                 Treat pattern as a (perl) regular expression.  See  perlreref(1)
>                 for  details.  Without  this  option,  pattern  is  treated as a
>                 literal string to search for.

Therefore my first try was

```
apt-file search --regexp .*ssl.*\.so.*
```

This, however, gave me results such as

> witty-examples: /usr/lib/Wt/examples/feature/client-ssl-auth/resources

which has no ".so" in the file name.

I played around a bit and came up with

```
apt-file search --regexp .*ssl.*\\.so.*
```

i.e. I escaped the backslash which was supposed to escape the dot. This gave me the results I wanted.

Could someone explain why I need a double backslash in this case?

Comment: Done. See below.

Comment: Take a look at [Bash Prompt Escape Sequences](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/bash-prompt-escape-sequences.html). "\\" means "a backslash". It turns out that you really entered *one* backslash, but had to escape it with the escape char (which happens to be the backslash).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a double backslash `\\` because the single backslash is not only the regex escape character but also the one your shell uses. E.g. you escape the dot, which on shell level just interprets to a regular dot, that is then passed to apt-get and machtes every character (as a regular dot usually does).

So the answer is, first the string is interpreted by the shell, where the backslash has one meaning, and **after** that, it is passed to apt-get. The regex-engine of apt-get then interpretes the preprocessed string again. There the backslash has been replaced (and also has a slightly different meaning).

Another solution is to put the regex in quotes as in:

```
apt-file search --regexp '.*ssl.*\.so.*'
```

Comment: you may use `[.]`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that as you are using no quoting, you need to escape both the shell and the regular expression interpreter both to interpret `.` as literal.

That's the reason why quoting is important. Your first pattern would work if you just use quotes around it :

```
apt-file search --regexp '.*ssl.*\.so.*'
```

The main thing to note that our final goal is to let the regex interpreter of `apt-file` to take the `.` literally rather than in the usual manner i.e. any single character.

The second case :

```
apt-file search --regexp .*ssl.*\\.so.*
```

- The first `\` here is to escape the shell as shell treats any `\` as the part of backslash escaped sequences e.g. shell treats `\n` as newline, `\t` as horizontal tab etc.

  With a single `\` as in `.*ssl.*\.so.*`, the shell treats `.` as `\` escaped special character but `.` has no special meaning to shell, so just `\` is removed by shell leaving only a `.`. With `\\.` shell removes the first `\` leaving behind `\.` as a literal `\` is represented by `\\` in shell.
- So we have `.*ssl.*\.so.*` left as the Regex pattern to be interpreted by `apt-file`'s Perl Regex interpreter. So you would get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use a quoted pattern, you have to escape the backslash for the RegEx:

```
apt-file search --regexp .*ssl.*\\.so.*
```

With a quoted pattern, you don't need that:

```
apt-file search --regexp '.*ssl.*\.so.*'
```

---

*Example*

```
$ apt-file search --regexp .*ssl.*\\.so.* > ~/tmp/bar
$ apt-file search --regexp '.*ssl.*\.so.*' > ~/tmp/foo
$ diff foo bar | wc -l
0
```

Comment: Just wanted do point that single quotes should work too, and maybe safer in the event the expression contains $ or something the shell can understand and try to substitute.

Comment: @CijcoSistems thank you, it's a good point. Changed.